# Posting data in Angularjs 2 using HTTP observable

Tags: http, angular, rxjs, observable

I am doing a POST request using the HTTP observable and the request is not being made and i am getting no errors, i have a service that defines the method i use to make the request

```
@Injectable()
export class MovingCompanyService {
constructor(private http: Http){}

registerCompany (body: Object): Observable<RegistrationDetailsModel> {
let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); //      ... Set content type to JSON
let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a   request option

return this.http.post("/moving_company/registration_form_2", body, options) // ...using post request
                    .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling     .json() on the response to return data
                    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
}   

}
```

And i have the component that calls this service method

```
constructor(private router: Router, private moving_company_service: MovingCompanyService) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
    if( Session.has("reg_frm_1")) {
        let frm1Data = Session.get("reg_frm_1");
        console.log("Received data from form 1 ", frm1Data);
    }
}

registerCompany(): void {
    let registrationOperation:Observable<RegistrationDetailsModel>;
    let registration_details = {
        reg_frm_1: Session.get("reg_frm_1"),
        reg_frm_2: this.model
    }
     this.moving_company_service.registerCompany(registration_details)
}
```

And i am calling the component method 'registerCompany' on a view click event like

```
<button (click)="registerCompany()">Submit</button>
```

I am not sure what i am missing or doing wrong, i have imported the rxjs library, the map and and catch operators and have all relevant imports in accordance,i would appreciate your assistance

Comment: whats the error ? Have you checked the network tab did you get entry in network tab ? Also have you checked the url is right where you are posting the data ?

Comment: where are you calling subscribe function ?

Comment: I think u r not calling subscribe on component that is the issue .please have a look on my answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: The networks tab does not show the request, there is no error in console tab and i am not sure if i know where or how to subscribe to the observable

Comment: So this means it is not called and As I mentioned in my answer please try that hopefully it will work I had same issues when I started angular2 . without subscribe nothing will happen .

Comment: I am not sure how to define errorMessage it shows an error

Comment: you can create a property on your component or you can delete it .

Comment: for more details on angular 2 . I have a github project i created it  for POC you can find it very useful . if you like visit https://github.com/yashveersingh83/ControlSubmissionClient/blob/master/src/app/recepient/recepient.add.component.ts

Comment: Thank you it seems to be making the request now after subscribing              POST http://localhost:3000/moving_company/registration_form_2 404 (Not Found)

Comment: can you please accept my answer and like it please .

Comment: Sure i did mark it as helpful and correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        this.moving_company_service.registerCompany
          ((registration_details).subscribe(
            r =>  r,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
            () => {  });
```

Comment: I have a string property on my component with name errorMessage